# Command to get list of files that are edited but not "opened" in perforce

Tags: git, perforce

Is there a command in Perforce to get a list of files that have been edited?
It seems the only way to do that is to open them using "p4 open " and do a "p4 diff".
I come from git where the easiest way to do that would be "git status".
Sometimes I don't want to "open" files but I still want to edit them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`p4 diff -se` will specifically give you files that are modified (determined via checksum comparison) but not opened for edit.

As tkosinski said you can also use `p4 reconcile` or `p4 status`.  Look carefully at the options to these commands; they can do a bunch of different things.  For example:

`p4 reconcile` will automatically open files for add, edit, delete, or move depending on whether they're new, modified, missing, or moved.

`p4 reconcile -e` will ONLY handle modified files (opening them for edit)

`p4 status` or `p4 reconcile -n` will ONLY report the differences (you can also combine this with the `-e` flag).

`p4 status -A` will open the file(s) for the appropriate action, making it basically a synonym for `p4 reconcile` (much like `p4 reconcile -n` is basically a synonym for `p4 status`).

Answer (score 1):

```
p4 reconcile
```

...will do that for you.

or, duh,

```
p4 status
```

...will do the same, but give you more clear info.

Comment: "p4 status -m" will give you the info, but NOT check the file out.